# Inclusions between $L^p$ continuous functions and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Working in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, consider on the one hand the space of continuous $L^{p}$ functions (let's use $V$ to denote this space), and on the other the family $\{ F_ {\alpha}^{p, q} \}_{\alpha, q}$ of Triebel-Lizorkin spaces. Since $F_{0}^{p, 2} = L^{p}$, we have $V \subseteq F_{0}^{p, 2}$; and I think (although I don't have a reference handy to check this) that $F_{d/p + \varepsilon}^{p, q} \subseteq V$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $q$ (or maybe there are restrictions on $q$, but I think it's something along these lines that's true). I'm wondering if there are any other inclusions that hold, aside from ones that would follow from combining the two above with the standard inclusions/embeddings between Triebel-Lizorkin spaces.